Read bytes from Modbus TCP/IP message in Big Endian byte order
I'm new with modbus and I need to write python script to read TCP/IP messages from Modbus client.
I need to read 4 bytes starting in address 002049 using Big-endian order.
so my questions are:

which library should I use- pymodbus or pymodbustcp?
what is the best practice for creating Modbus Client- auto_open=True/False, auto_close=True/False?
How can I read Bytes instead of bits?
How can I set the bytes values in Big-endian order?

I tried to use How to read byte order endian BIG with Python? but couldn't find an answer.
---UPDATE---
how can I do it using AsyncModbusTcpClient?

You READ them in whatever order they arrive.  You can then use the struct module to convert the byte stream to an integer.  That's where endianness is important.  The only thing you can read is bytes.

@TimRoberts, so the second argument in read_holding_registers(reg_addr, reg_nb=1) method is number of bytes?

No, it is number of registers.

@TimRoberts does 2 registers equal to 4 bytes?

Yes, all modbus registers are 16 bits or 2 bytes.

Code to read 4 bytes (2 registers) starting at address 2049 (address 002049 in Modbus):
from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient

def read_modbus_registers(ip_address, port, start_address, num_registers):
    # Create a Modbus TCP client
    client = ModbusClient(host=ip_address, port=port, auto_open=True)

    if client.is_open():
        result = client.read_holding_registers(start_address, num_registers)

        if result:
            # Combine the two registers into a single 32-bit integer (big-endian order)
            value = (result[0] << 16) | result[1]
            print(f"Value read from address {start_address}: {value}")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to read from Modbus server: {client.last_error}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to connect to Modbus server at {ip_address}:{port}")

    # Close the Modbus TCP client
    client.close()

# Modbus TCP server configuration
modbus_ip = "your_modbus_server_ip"
modbus_port = 502  # Modbus TCP port

# Address and number of registers to read
start_address = 2049  # Address 002049 in Modbus
num_registers = 2  # Reading 4 bytes (2 registers)

# Read Modbus registers
read_modbus_registers(modbus_ip, modbus_port, start_address, num_registers)

To perform the task asynchronously, we need to use await when interacting with the client.
import asyncio
from pyModbusTCP.asyncio import AsyncModbusTcpClient

async def read_modbus_registers_async(ip_address, port, start_address, num_registers):
    # Create an async client instance
    client = AsyncModbusTcpClient(host=ip_address, port=port)

    try:
        # Connect to the Modbus server
        await client.connect()

        if client.is_connected:
            # Read registers
            result = await client.read_holding_registers(start_address, num_registers)

            if result:
                # Combine the registers
                value = (result[0] << 16) | result[1]
                print(f"Value read from address {start_address}: {value}")
            else:
                print(f"Failed to read from Modbus server: {client.last_error}")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to connect to Modbus server at {ip_address}:{port}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

    finally:
        # Close the Modbus TCP client
        await client.close()

# Modbus TCP server configuration
modbus_ip = "your_modbus_server_ip"
modbus_port = 502  # Modbus TCP port

# Address and number of registers to read
start_address = 2049  # Address 002049 in Modbus
num_registers = 2  # Reading 4 bytes (2 registers)

# Create an event loop and run the asynchronous function
async def main():
    await read_modbus_registers_async(modbus_ip, modbus_port, start_address, num_registers)

# Run the event loop
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())


how can I change this code to use AsyncModbusTcpClient class?

I've updated the answer to include an async solution.
